# Distribution of a transform of bivariate to univariate random variable?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, transformation

Suppose we have two random variables

$$R\sim U[1-\varepsilon,1]\;\;\;\;\; \Theta\sim U[0,2\pi],$$

and a third random variable

$$X=g(R,\Theta)=R\cos\Theta.$$

What is the density $p_X(x)$?

The section [Transformations of Random Variables](http://www.randomservices.org/random/dist/Transformations.html) on Random contains a few results, the most general being the *Distribution Function Method*, since the *Change of Variables Method* does not seem to apply as $g$ is neither one-to-one (although can be made by restricting $\Theta$ and using symmetry) or strictly increasing/decreasing.

One idea is to introduce an auxiliary random variable $Y=R\sin\Theta$, define the bivariate transform $[X,Y] = [g_1(R,\Theta), g_2(R,\Theta)] = [R\cos\Theta, R\sin\Theta]$ and then solve

$$p_{X,Y}(x,y) = p_{R,\Theta}\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2},\arctan\left(\frac{x}{y} \right) \right)|J_h(x,y)|$$

where $h(X,Y)$ is the inverse transform of $g$, and then marginalize over $Y$. Although I remain uncertain whether this formula is applicable for the transform $h$. Is there a more direct or alternative method to find the marginal density $p_X$?

I created a few plots of the marginal of $X$ by simulation to visualize what its distribution looks like for various values of $\varepsilon$.

[image]

Comment: The histograms are too "spiky": it means that 1) You should not take that many classes 2) and, moreover that you have not done enough simulations. If you are with Matlab, don't hesitate to do several hundred of thousands of trials...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $\delta=1-\epsilon\ge0$, for $x\ge0$ we have
\begin{align}
\def\pro#1{\textsf{Pr}\left(#1\right)}
\pro{X\ge x}&=\pro{R\cos\Theta\ge x}\\
&=\pro{\cos\Theta\ge\frac xR}\\
&=\int_\delta^1\pro{\cos\Theta\ge\frac xr}\mathrm dr\\
&=\begin{cases}
\frac1{\epsilon\pi}\int_\delta^1\arccos\frac xr\mathrm dr&0\le x\le\delta\\
\frac1{\epsilon\pi}\int_x^1\arccos\frac xr\mathrm dr&\delta\le x\le1\\
0&x\ge1
\end{cases}\\
&=\begin{cases}
\frac1{\epsilon\pi}\left(\arccos x-x\log\left(\sqrt{1-x^2}+1\right)-\delta\arccos\frac x\delta+x\log\left(\sqrt{\delta^2-x^2}+\delta\right)\right)&0\le x\le\delta\\
\frac1{\epsilon\pi}\left(\arccos x-x\log\left(\sqrt{1-x^2}+1\right)+x\log x\right)&\delta\le x\le1\\
0&x\ge1\;.
\end{cases}
\end{align}

The density is the negative derivative of this probability with respect to $x$:

$$
p_X(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac1{\epsilon\pi}\left(\log\left(\sqrt{1-x^2}+1\right)-\log\left(\sqrt{\delta^2-x^2}+\delta\right)\right)&0\le x\le\delta\\
\frac1{\epsilon\pi}\left(\log\left(\sqrt{1-x^2}+1\right)-\log x\right)&\delta\le x\le1\\
0&x\ge1\;.
\end{cases}
$$

If you don't need the cumulative distribution function, you can avoid the detour of integrating the arccosine by applying the derivative with respect to $x$ directly to the integrals.

Here's a plot of the density for the four intermediate cases you simulated, $\epsilon=0.1,0.2,0.5,0.7$:

[image: density for intermediate values of epsilon]